# Update - Xamarin (Visual Studio) iOS Universal project with Storyboard - simulators not being listed

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, ios-simulator, universal

I am using the following

```
Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 
Xamarin 3.9.236.0
Xamarin.iOS 8.6.0.0.
```

When I create a blank Universal iOS app the set of simulators are displayed.
When a Universal Single App project is created, the list of simulators does not appear in Visual Studio.

Is there a fix or workaround available?

Update - I installed Xcode 6 and it started working. The project type must have needed some feature not available in Xcode 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Xcode 6 and it started working. The project type must have needed some feature not available in Xcode 5